# C# Xamarin Manifest issue

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have [this][1] error in visual studio after changing pointing API of android. Do someone know how fix it?
Thank you.

Here is manifest:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

As the error suggests to your AndroidManifest in the `Application` element